# Best practice when not implementing IValueConvert.ConvertBack

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Just wondering what people think is the best practice when implementing an IValueConverter which does not have a meaningfull ConvertBack implementation (or one that is only to be used as OneWay)?

Should it throw (and in that case what exception), return null or return some default value.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The documentation for [`IValueConverter.ConvertBack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convertback) recommends returning [`DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty.unsetvalue).

> The data binding engine does not catch
>   exceptions that are thrown by a
>   user-supplied converter. Any exception
>   that is thrown by the ConvertBack
>   method, or any uncaught exceptions
>   that are thrown by methods that the
>   ConvertBack method calls, are treated
>   as run-time errors. Handle anticipated
>   problems by returning
>   DependencyProperty.UnsetValue.

Answer (score 8):

According Microsoft, you should return `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`

Answer (score 7):

I agree with @Todd White's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/265544/3195477).

Additionally, in order to save time, you can implement a base converter class which implements `ConvertBack` for you so you don't have to implement it every time saving duplicate code.

Technically, you don't have to override `Convert` either; But it has to be implemented in `ConverterBase` since it implements all methods of the `IValueConverter` interface. In practice, you will be overriding `Convert` every time and `ConvertBack` can be ignored most of the time.

```
public class ConverterBase : IValueConverter
{
    public virtual object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
    public virtual object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}

public class VisibilityConverter : ConverterBase
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((bool)value ^ (parameter as bool? == true)).ToVisibility();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

When ConvertBack contains no functionality, and you are **not expecting** it to be called, throw a NotImplementedException. It shouldn't have been called and therefore you want a run time exception.

If ConvertBack is **intentionally** being called, then you had better provide an implementation for it. One option is just to return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue, or handle exceptions within your ConvertBack implementation by returning DependencyProperty.UnsetValue.

My justification for this would be: returning a  DependencyProperty.UnsetValue instead of throwing a NotImplementedException makes it **unobvious** when a ConvertBack method is being invoked when you really never intended it to be. Maybe it should have some functionality now that it is being invoked and throwing a run time exception.  It would be much harder to discover the missing ConvertBack functionality if it is just returning DependencyProperty.UnsetValue.

Comment: If you're going to do this, you should be using `NotSupportedException`, `NotImplementedException` is for functionality which is not currently implemented but will be.