# What is best practise for IValueConverter?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

What is best practise for [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx): Is it ok to put Exception in Convert method or should it return "something"?

Here is an example:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(float), typeof(String))]
public class PercentConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
            return string.Empty;

        if (value is float) //Edited to support CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            return string.Format(culture, "{0:n}{1}", ((float)value) * 100, "%");

        //** Is it ok to put Exception here or should I return "something" here? **
        throw new Exception("Can't convert from " + value.GetType().Name + ". Expected type if float.");
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Converting back is not implemented in " + this.GetType());
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best practice when not implementing IValueConvert.ConvertBack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265515/best-practice-when-not-implementing-ivalueconvert-convertback)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF ValueConverter - Standard return for unconvertible value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992769/wpf-valueconverter-standard-return-for-unconvertible-value)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you fail to convert (malformed values, types, ...), return [DependencyProperty.UnsetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.unsetvalue.aspx).

It indicates that the converter produced no value and that the binding uses the FallbackValue, if available, or the default value instead.

Also, you should convert data with culture-specific conversion or invariant conversions to be on the safe side.

Comment: Should I return string.Empty?

Comment: `return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;`
There are other return values that you can modify the behaviour of the binding engine with. You can follow the link I have provided in my answer to read about it further. Here is a sample of using `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convert.aspx

Comment: Per [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convert.aspx), you can use `Binding.DoNothing` if the binding shouldn't set a particular value. This should be more use in things like multivalueconverters though.

Answer (score 8):

I personally recommend using singleton converters. Then you don't have to create an instance at every usage site, but can reference the converter like this:

```
Converter={x:Static SomeNamespace:SomeConverter.Instance}
```

Answer (score 3):

You've ignored `CultureInfo`  while parsing the string.

Always take in to account the culture info passed otherwise it would always work on Thread's CurrentCulture.

I could give some thing like "7.34,123" as input, would your code work?