# How to highlight row for IsSelected

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, background, itemcontainerstyle

I want to highlight the row when I select from my `ListView` but I cant get it to work. Can anyone look at what I have and tell me what I'm doing wrong? Another question is What about having a property in my ViewModel and setting the `Background` color based on the bool value, how can that be achieve?

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
            </Trigger>

            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is the item template for the `ListView` automatically adds the "Selected highlight" of brush type `SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey` - the "true solution" would be to override the item template definition, but one way you can get what you're after here is something like this:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Green"/>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a Bool value to a Color brush by using an interface called `IValueConverter`.

Here's a related post: [What is best practise for IValueConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944553/what-is-best-practise-for-ivalueconverter)

Answer (score 0):

```
            <ListView  Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SimpleList}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Olive">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <EventSetter Event="MouseEnter" Handler="listBox1_ListBoxItem_MouseEnter"/>
                        <EventSetter Event="MouseLeave" Handler="listBox1_ListBoxItem_MouseLeave"/>
                        <Style.Resources>
                            <!-- Background of selected item when focussed -->
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                                Color="Green"/>
                            <!-- Background of selected item when not focussed -->
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}"
                                Color="Yellow" />
                        </Style.Resources>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <!--<Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />-->
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: The normal trigger he had for "IsMouseOver" should work fine - it's the selected style which gets overriden by the ItemTemplate.