# Correct way to not implement ConvertBack on a IMultiValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, imultivalueconverter

I have an object that implements `IMultiValueConverter`. It is used to bind visibility of a column based upon a particular permutation of a specific bool value and a specific enum value, both part of the bound data. The ConvertBack method self evidently has no meaning.

On a regular IValueConverter, I could return [Binding.DoNothing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.donothing(v=vs.110).aspx), but that is not an `object[]` so won't compile.

I currently throw an exception, but that doesn't feel ideal. Is there a better way?

Comment: try this : public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
  {
   return new object[] {value};
  }

Comment: you can try even this as well : public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new[] { value, Binding.DoNothing};
    }     ............OR.............. public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new[] {Binding.DoNothing};
    }

Comment: Why are you using `IMultiValueConverter` for controlling visibility of a column? It is supoosed to be used for converting. Sure the timing of when that is called may be ideal for controlling visibility but that does not make it the right choice for what you are doing. Although many people misuse it like that and then face the questions you are facing.

Comment: See [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/143322/wpf-controls-visibility-throught-imultivalueconverter) please.

Comment: What @GaurangDave suggests won't work, because if you return an object array, its length must match the number of Bindings in the MultiBinding.

Comment: Related: [Best practice when not implementing IValueConvert.ConvertBack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265515/best-practice-when-not-implementing-ivalueconvert-convertback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to implement the `ConvertBack` method of an IValueConverter or an IMultiValueConverter that does not support back-conversion is to throw a `NotSupportedException`.

Returning `Binding.DoNothing` makes no sense, as the method should never be called anyway. But if it is ever called unexpectedly, you would rightly get an exception that tells you what went wrong.

```
public object[] ConvertBack(
    object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Comment: I can see how NotSupportedException is justified in such a situation. I think Gaurang Dave's suggestion might work given for this converter I know exactly the number of parameters. CodingYoshi has a reasonable point that a lot of the time this should be done by style triggers. I am not sure that would be able to work with enum HasFlag though and would mean that I would lose the test case coverage already on the behaviour. Accordingly, accepting this.

Comment: This answer should clarify that the _"correct"_ way described applies only when the `ConvertBack()` method is in fact not to be used. For both `IValueConverter` and `IMultiValueConverter`, there are valid use scenarios for the `ConvertBack()` method, and this answer is confusing neophytes who are taking the wording literally (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58844254/why-does-imultivalueconverter-convertback-even-exist-has-anyone-implemented-it).

Comment: @PeterDuniho That detail is pretty clear in the question title.

Comment: For an `IMultiValueConverter` that does not support `ConvertBack`, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.convertback?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) actually states *"Return `null` to indicate that the converter cannot perform the conversion or that it does not support conversion in this direction."*

Answer (score 2):

## Return `null`

For `IMultiValueConverter`, the [`ConvertBack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.convertback) documentation specifically states:

> Return `null` to indicate that the converter *cannot perform the
>   conversion or that it does not support conversion in this direction*.

Comment: @Clemens It seems better to me to fail gracefully rather than crash the entire program because of a binding issue. If you're writing a converter to use yourself, you can easily look at the code to see if `ConvertBack` is supported, and if you're providing it as part of a library, your documentation should clearly state whether it can be used or not. If someone is purposefully using `ConvertBack`, they will be expecting it to return a value and should quickly see that it's not giving them what they expected, and if they're doing it unknowningly, does it hurt if it's not giving them a value?

Comment: "crash the entire program because of a binding issue" - you are confusing things. An exception that clearly indicates that something unexpected has happened is not a crash. It is something you *want* to see - at least if you are a developer.

Comment: @Clemens An exception that terminates execution is a crash.

Comment: @Clemens It's still a crash, developer or not. All you are saying is that you think that an unrecoverable crash is a desirable situation to aid developing, and I disagree.

Comment: This is the correct answer. What the doc says is, by definition, the truth.