# Why does IMultiValueConverter.ConvertBack even exist? Has anyone implemented it?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

According to [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50054267/correct-way-to-not-implement-convertback-on-a-imultivalueconverter?rq=1), the proper way to implement IMultiValueConverter.ConvertBack is to throw a NotSupportedException.  If that is the case, why does this method even exist?

Maybe it's not true.   Certainly [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.convertback?view=netframework-4.8) discusses all sorts of a ways for an implementation to indicate it does not support the conversion that do not involve throwing an exception.  But I have never seen an implementation that actually did the conversion.

Has anyone ever actually implemented this function?

Comment: `ConvertBack` is to send value back to `ViewModel` which `ViewModel` can understand. that means `Binded property`

Comment: You misunderstood that answer. The question asks how to implement ConvertBack in a converter that supports only forward-, but not back-conversion. If your converter is supposed to support both directions, you would of course write a proper ConvertBack  implementation.

Comment: You could even write a converter that *only* supports ConvertBack, which would hypothetically be used in a OneWayToSource Binding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Has anyone ever actually implemented this function?

Yes.

Oh, I'm sorry. Did you want something more than that? :)

You have misunderstood the question you're referencing. The question itself makes clear that their specific scenario has no meaningful use for the `ConvertBack()` method, and they are asking what the method should do *in that specific case*. The posted answer addresses that specific case, not every single implementation of `IMultiValueConverter`.

I have certainly implemented the method myself with actual logic in the past. A couple of examples where you might find doing so useful are:

1. A converter that merges three color components – red, green, and blue – into a single `Color` value for binding to some type of color-picker control. The `Convert()` method would compose the three channels into the single `Color` value, while the `ConvertBack()` method would decompose the `Color` value back to three constituent properties.
2. A converter that formats a time value represented as three different properties – hours, minutes, and seconds – as a text string with the format `"HH:MM:SS"`. The `Convert()` method would combine the values with the `':'` separator character, while the `ConvertBack()` method would split the values apart and parse them back as their original integer values.

Those are just a couple of reasonable examples. Of course in the real-world, there are countless reasons one might actually provide a real implementation for the `ConvertBack()` method.

Of course, there are just as many scenarios where the binding is one-way only, and there's no meaningful way to implement the `ConvertBack()` method. For those scenarios, throw `NotSupportedException()`, just as [the referenced Q&A suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50054267/correct-way-to-not-implement-convertback-on-a-imultivalueconverter).

Comment: The `IMultiValueConverter` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.convertback) actually states that you should return `null` to indicate that the conversion cannot be performed or that conversion in that direction is not supported, and recommends that no exceptions be intentionally thrown from `ConvertBack`.